i want to install the nvidia 390 driver on ubuntu 24.01
so to do that i installed the old kernel 5.15.150 and booted in recovery mode but everything was crushed (apps not opening, gnome bugged, WiFi not working)
now am trying with more recent kernel 6.4 but i am afraid i would not find it.
is there anyone one that tried to install it and it worked?

So, the 6.4 kernel method worked

I demoted the kernel

Updated the system
sudo apt install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r''')


Updated Prerequisites for the driver, then I found it in the 'additional drivers' app.


wp this method broke the system the nouveau driver just died as well as gnome DE anyway i gave up (ubuntu 22.04)

Please don't forget to accept your answer. You can accept your answer tomorrow at the current time only 24 hours later from now. To mark your answer as accepted click the gray check beside your answer which will change color from gray to green when it is clicked.
